# How to use onChange in multi-select react form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-bootstrap, onchange

In case of multi-select , can someone help me with the onChange function ?

What can I pass inside `updateFormState( )` to make the code work. Thanks.

```
const formState = {
 fruits: "",
}; 


function updateFormState(key, value) {
  formState[key] = value;
}

const [fruits] = useState([]);

      <Form.Label>fruits</Form.Label>
          <MultiSelect
           options={[
            { label: "Grapes ", value: "grapes" },
            { label: "Mango ", value: "mango" },
            { label: "Strawberry ", value: "strawberry", disabled: true },
            ]}
           id="fruits" 
           labelledBy="Select"
           value={fruits}
           onChange={(e) => updateFormState( )}
          />
         </Form.Group>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi try this i hope it usefull

```
  const [fruits, setFruits] = useState();
  console.log("fruits",fruits);

  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={(e) => setFruits(e.target.value)} value={fruits}>
        <option value='' selected disabled hidden>
          select a fruits
        </option>
        <option value='apple'>apple</option>
        <option value='banana'>banana</option>
        <option value='orange'>orange</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: I am getting an error "react-dom.development.js:4091 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')" . Also, it doesn't provide the multi-select dropdown feature.